# connect server using socket without port

Tags: c#, .net-core, network-programming

I want to connect(ping) server without specifying socket below is the code I am using

```
public static bool PingServerWithSocket(string hostname )
    {
        bool result = false;

            try
            {
                var sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                sock.Blocking = true;


                IPAddress ipaddes = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname).AddressList[0];
                sock.Connect(ipaddes, 50001); 
                result= true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.InnerException ?? "");
                result = false;
            }


        return result;
    }
```

Please help me to ping server using socket without port..

Comment: "Ping" as in "try a connect via TCP" or as in "[ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)"-Ping ?

Comment: If you want a "true" ping, then [read more about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) and learn how it really works.

Comment: need to connect via tcp

Comment: But a socket is a combination of IP and port by definition. What exactly do you want to do? Check weather the server is online or not? Send a "true" ping, as mentioned by 'Some programmer dude'?